# any practices ,samples for ERD?

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, erd, database-normalization

Q:

I want any web sites or books just for training on **ERD** and **normalization**. I want a lot of ***sample, practices, and case studies*** with recommended answers, to strengthen my skill in database design and avoid the poor database designs I've made.

**Note:** I don't need books to explain the concepts, what I need is practices, examples, and case studies with recommended answers.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would consider [Object Role Modelling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_role_modelling) over ERM using [NORMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NORMA) or some such.

There is small group on [linkedin](http://www.linkedin.com/groups?mostPopular=&gid=1743337) about ORM, as well a [short discussion](http://dbaspot.com/forums/databases/157556-what-better-database-design-uml-erm.html) over on dbaspot.

For normalization, I'd start with [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and then search

Answer (score 3):

[Database Design Using Entity-Relationship Diagram](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0849315484) by Sikha Bagui and Richard Earp should be a good starting point.

The [Database Management System](http://www.youtube.com/user/nptelhrd#g/c/9426FE14B809CC41) lecture series, published by the Indian Institute of Technology (IIT), is another good resource.

Answer (score 2):

I think the Database Programmer blog is worth reading.  It's got some nice stuff on [normalization](http://database-programmer.blogspot.com/search/label/normalization), but I'm sure any tutorial that Google brought back would be sufficient.